# on AppStore, How to update my app differently by region?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

In short word, I want have different release rhythm for different region.

I knew select territories there. BUT, that's for whole APP, if I uncheck US, the app will been removed from US app store, right ?

What I want is select territories for one version, or the version's publish target region.

e.g:

1. A old version 1.0.0 is now at AppStore for all region, US and CHINA can install 1.0.0;
2. Then upload a new version 1.2.0, we want release it today at China, but don't release it at other region, so CHINA can install 1.2.0, US still can install 1.0.0;
3. After a week (or longer) we release 1.2.0 for other region, so CHINA and US can install 1.2.0;

Is there any way to make it happen ?

Comment: No.  You can stage the release over a short time period, but users are selected for upgrade randomly.  You can't stage the update by geographic region.  You would need to control functionality within the app by detecting the user's region

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That means all global (ios) app have to update synchronously between different regions ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Currently it's not possible to have a phased release based on territories. If you check the official phased release docs: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev3d65fcee1

> If you choose this option, your version update will be released over a
>   7-day period to a percentage of your users (selected at random by
>   their Apple ID) on iOS with automatic updates turned on. Users are not
>   notified that that they are in a phased release of your app.

This is the release pattern:
[image]